# How to represent single quote character literal in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to run a simple program that takes a String as an input
and returns the same String only with changes to certain characters
(flip `.` and `,` change `!` to `?` etc).

Most of the time I just read the original String char by char and each time a char meets one of my criterias, it is modified.

There is one char I'm having an issue with. I wish that every time a user
types in `'` I would return them `w`.

I tried to do this:

```
if ( charInput == ' ' '){
    return 'w'
}
```

Of course it doesn't compile. How should I bypass this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your question by including the code of the program.

Comment: you need to escape the `'` using \

Comment: You need to escape the character: `'\''`

Comment: `if ( charInput == '\'') {`...

Comment: Also you might want to look at `replaceAll()`

Comment: oh, ok. used the \, now it works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use escape sequence,like below

**`if(charInput == '\'' ){`**

And if you want replace you can just use `replace()` or `replaceAll()` to replace the particular character in a String.

```
someString.replace('\'','w');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem

```
if (charInput == '\''){
    return 'w';
}
```

On another note, it might be worth changing this if statement to a switch, e.g:

```
switch (charInput){
    case '\'':
        return 'w';
        break;
    case 'a':
        return 'b';
        break;
}
```

Also note that you can't have whitespace around the quotes unless that's what you want to match... `' a '` is not the same as `'a'` and I don't believe the former will compile.